# Is there a virtual particle connection between entangled particles?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, virtual-particles

Is there a virtual particle, or an excitation of the field, between entangled particles?  I know that there are many entangled particles within an atom and these probably have virtual particle connections between them.  But does this extend to entangled particles at a distance?

Comment: see this talk https://www.tp.nt.uni-siegen.de/talks/files/Mannel_Kolloquium_der_Fakultaet_4,_Uni_Siegen_07-05-2014.pdf . All those intermediate lines in the Feynman diagram represent virtual particles.

Comment: @annav. Those diagrams show how a virtual particle is involved in the creation of the entangled pair. I am asking if there remains a virtual connection between the entangled pair after creation, and even if they are moved to some distance apart?

Comment: It is evident that the time component in the diagrams goes to infinity, or to the next interaction, so the mathematics remains